# White blocking screen when put youtube in full-screen mode

Tags: 12.04, freeze, youtube

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS..

In most cases, when I put a video in a **Full screen** on **YouTube** (I am not using HTML5, I am using *Flash Player*), and when try to **exit the full screen mode**, I got my screen turned to a *blocking white screen*.

This prevents me from doing anything on my box but restart from <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd> terminal.

Actually I don't know where exactly to report this issue, so I put it here appreciating any help.

**PS:**
I could see this issue on 13.04 also.

Comment: Same problem is here: Ubuntu 12.04 x64 & Chrome

Comment: It would be better if you provide some screenshots of the exact situation. It would help us to solve the issue. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't use **Chrome**, ignore this answer.

---

If you use **Chrome**, the problem doesn't come frome Flash "as it" but the `PPAPI library` used by Chrome and Adobe, developping together *PepperFlash* (*/opt/google/chrome/PepperFlash/libpepflashplayer.so*).

You can desactivate it, so Chrome will use the `NPAPI`, like other navigators (you must have flashplugin : `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`)

1) Open Chrome and type in the omnibox (the URL bar) :

`chrome://plugins/`

2) Press "+ details" in the top-right corner of the page.

3) Scroll down to **Adobe Flash Player**

4) Find the `Type: PPAPI` line

5) Click on "disable" right below that line.

Restart Chrome and try a full-screen flash video again.

Comment: Yeah, this does help somewhat. But since about a week or so the NPAPI flash plugin is crashing all the time.

Answer (score 0):

When you make that, I suggest you to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd> 
and type

```
ps aux | grep gnome-session
```

get the PID example 1255

```
kill 1255
```

and that you can install

```
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

Comment: Why would anyone need to kill his D.E. to install flash ?